# Slow query in Java by JDBC but not in other systems (TOAD)

Tags: java, performance, oracle, jdbc

Hello i have a query to an Oracle System which involves a view which joins other tables by apliying an TO_NUMBER() to the tables primary key.

If i do the query using TOAD the query is very fast (1 sec for 800 regs). If i do the same query in a java program by JDBC with a String literal (not a parametrized query), the time is good too.

But if i use a parametriced query by an PreparedStatement the query takes 1 min to fetch the same registers. I know that using constant values produce distinct execution plan than using parameters... but if i remove the TO_NUMBER funcions in the joins of the view, the parametriced query is fast too.

- Is the parameters / TO_NUMBER() union preventing to use the PK index of the joined tables?
- is there a workaround to solve this (i need the parameters on the query and also the TO_NUMBER function)?

P.D. sry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

without additional information, we can only assume that an index isn't being used with the to_number() function is applied to the column. As shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158188/index-not-used-due-to-type-conversion), a type conversion can prevent the optimizer from using an index.

In general:

- when you add a function to a column (i-e: `to_number(id)`) the optimizer won't be able to use the regular indexes on that column,
- if it is possible, you should use the column raw. For exemple: instead of `WHERE trunc(col) = DATE '2009-08-27'` you should use: `WHERE col >= DATE '2009-08-27' AND col < DATE '2009-08-28'`
- if you really have to apply a function to a column, you can use a [function-based index](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm#i2078649)

Comment: i know that apliying an function on a column can prevent the use of the column index, but the extrange thing is that it only happens when the query is parametrized

Comment: @Telcontar: What might happen is that the datatype of your constant (with Toad or with a dynamicly built sql) and the datatype of your parameter are different. This could lead to a situation where the plan for a parametrized query is suboptimal because of implicit conversion. Can you give us a simple exemple of a query where you encouter this issue ?

Comment: The query is 

SELECT * FROM V_DAT_AJPR_CON_DESCRIP_C WHERE ENTIDAD=7777 AND TO_NUMBER(CFPERIOD)=TO_NUMBER(251) AND CFSUBGRP='S0000' AND ID_VERSION=6

where the four values are dinamic

the view use multiple joins with other tables of the form CFPERIOD, ID, FIELD_1, ... FIELD_N and the pk is (CFPERIOD,ID)

and the join with the view is
TO_NUMBER(V.CFPERIOD)=TO_NUMBER(T.CFPERIOD) AND
V.ID=T.ID

Answer (score 2):

Check that the data type of the Java variable passed in the parameter is compatible with the Oracle data type.  I have seen symptoms similar to yours when passing Java TIMESTAMP's through a bind variable that was being compared to Oracle DATE columns - literal string query OK, test case in PL/SQL with (date) bind OK, Java code w/ mismatch not OK.

[Edit]
I think you've provided some additional information since the original posting.  The best way to understand what is happening with the slightly different forms (binds vs. literals) of the query from different environments (Java vs. Toad) is to enable tracing during the execution and compare the execution paths from the resulting trace files.  This will require that you have access to the database host to retrieve the files.

- In Toad, open an interactive SQL
  window (I don't use Toad but I'm sure
  you'll understand what I mean) and
  issue the SQL command "alter session
  set sql_trace=true"
- Run your query - it would be a good
  idea to add a comment to the query
  such as "/* Toad with literals */"
- For the Java test, build a test case
  that issues the "alter session..."
  statement and then runs the query. 
  Again, add a comment to the query to
  identify it as coming from the Java
  test.
- Don't worry about turning the tracing
  off - this will happen when the
  sessions are disconnected and in some
  cases the disconnection method of
  stopping the trace is preferred.
- Find out where your trace files on
  the database host are by "select
  value from v$parameter where name
  like 'user_dump_dest' "
- Find the .trc files by searching for
  the query comment strings
- Use the TKPROF utility from the OS
  command line to process the trace
  file - " tkprof filename.trc tkprof
  filename.out "
- Examine/post the execution paths and
  times that you see.

Comment: the datatype comparation is between numbers and strings, some of the strings start with 0's which i can't remove from the tables of the view (i can`t write to them)

Comment: I've added some information in my original answer about tracing the execution which should help you/us analyze what's actually happening.

Comment: Sry i have forgotten this question (which is already unanswerd), but i can't do the test you suggest, i 'm not the dba and i can only create tables/views, procedures, packages... but not trace querys. I pass it to the DBA but i don't think he do anything

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure someone hasn't set the property oracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true

This is sometimes done to resolve unicode problems but it means all columns are treated as nvarchars. If you have an index on a varchar column, it won't be used because oracle has to use a function to convert the character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

This actual an issue relate with ORACLE server side configuration, just change Cursor_Sharing to EXACT if origin is FORCE