# Dapper, Oracle and Command Parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, orm, parameters, dapper

I have a table in Oracle named MESSAGE and it has a column TERMINALID (VARCHAR2 8 NOT NULL); and there is an index for this column. There are about 300,000,000 records in this table.

Now, **this works fine (0.0 seconds)**:

```
using (var con = new OracleConnection(connectionString2))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("PTerminalId", value: "04447777", dbType: System.Data.DbType.AnsiString);
        Console.WriteLine("ora - messages #{0}", con.Query<decimal>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MESSAGE WHERE TERMINALID=:PTerminalId", param: parameters).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    finally { con.Close(); }
}
```

And **this fails (times out)**:

```
using (var con = new OracleConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.GSMConnectionString2))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("ora - messages #{0}", con.Query<decimal>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GSM.MESSAGE WHERE TERMINALID=:PTerminalId", param: new { PTerminalId = "04447777" }).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    finally { con.Close(); }
}
```

Why it's so?

Comment: First code runs in 0.0 seconds; second code times out.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the datatype of the parameter in the second query?

Comment: No; and I don't like it.

Comment: It might be the reason why the first query uses the index and the second doesn't: [a datatype mismatch can make indexes unusable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158188/index-not-used-due-to-type-conversion/1158272#1158272). A SQL trace of both queries would likely provide an explanation.

Comment: Tnx; That sounds like the cause. I'll try it on a table with fewer records to see if it actually returns something and report back.

Comment: Yes, that should be it. Because on another table that has the same index but with fewer records (~25,000) second code runs nearly 40% slower. So actually it is not using the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically: what @Vincent said: [a datatype mismatch can make indexes unusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158188/index-not-used-due-to-type-conversion/1158272#1158272).

Without additional information, dapper makes some assumptions. One of those assumptions is that your string is going to continue to be unicode at the database, so it defaults to `DbType.String`. In most cases this is either correct or adequate, but it can misbehave in some scenarios - which is why we also provide the facility (via `DynamicParameters`) to be more explicit about both the type and length of the string parameter to add.